# The root element must be well-formed: mTurks

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I'm developing a survey through mechanicalTurks. When I run this code in a webpage it runs without error; but, when I try to post my HIT  to the [sandbox](https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/) I get the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :3:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[ERROR] Error creating HIT 1 (test): [3,2] The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

I imagine this is a problem with my `.question` file but I can't seem to find the error. I've pasted an example version of my `.question` file below:

```
<!-- Bootstrap v3.0.3 -->
<link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/bs30/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="container" id="Survey" style="margin-bottom:15px; padding: 10px 10px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#333333; font-size:0.9em;">
<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-12"><!-- Instructions -->
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading"><strong>Instructions</strong></div>

<div class="panel-body">
<p><strong>DIRECTIONS</strong></p>

<p><strong>1. XXXX</strong></p>

<p><strong>2. XXXX <u>ONE</u>response</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Instructions --><!-- Survey Body -->

<div></div>
<label>ITEM:</label> ${Examples}

<fieldset>
<p style="line-height: 20px;"><u style="line-height: 20px;"><strong>directions</strong></u></p>

<p style="line-height: 20px;">

<input name="question" type="radio" value="1" />1) XXXXXX<br />

<input name="question" type="radio" value="2" /><span style="line-height: 20px; background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);">2) XXXXX <u>XXX</u>:XXXX<em>XXX</em> XXX</span><br />

<input name="question" type="radio" value="3" /><span style="line-height: 20px; background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);">3) XXXX<em>and;</em>XXXX <u>TIP</u>XXXX<em>XXX</em> apply</span><br />

<p style="line-height: 20px;"><input name="question" type="radio" value="8" />8);None of the above</p>
</fieldset>
</div>
</section>
<!-- End Survey Body --><!-- close container -->
<style type="text/css">fieldset {
    padding: 10px;
    background:#fbfbfb;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the different arguments. For example, in the line:

```
<input name="question" type="radio" value="1" />1) XXXXXX<br />
```

You don't start the text with `<b>`.

You should be coding using XML. Check out the sample's Amazon includes in the CLT file.